# Run time GUI creation using python.Actually i want in my Panel the checkbox name should be given from an excel file which has been opened

Tags: python-2.7

Code:

```
self.CheckBox1 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Full Blockage', pos=(10, 40), size=(80, 40), style=0,
                                     validator=wx.DefaultValidator, name='BlurCheckBox')
```

I am loading the excel from from panel which have been already created only I want that the checkbox in the panel should be dynamic in nature. i.e.label='Full Blockage' should be replaced by label='self.sheet.cell(row=self.mro_Frame, column=i).value'

Comment: I am loading the excel from from panel which have been already created only i want that the checkbox in the panel should be dynamic in nature. i.e.label='Full Blockage' should be replaced by label='self.sheet.cell(row=self.mro_Frame, column=i).value'

Comment: Add more details and format

Comment: I did it....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
self.mworkbook = load_workbook(filename)
self.sheet = self.mworkbook.active
self.mCheckBox1 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, label=self.sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value, pos=(10, 260), size=(80, 40), style=0,
                                  validator=wx.DefaultValidator, name='M_FullBlockage')
```

Comment: But you need to perform this after loading an excel file during run time.